# How can I hide <li> instead of wrapping <li> to a new line

Tags: html, css

I have horizontal list:

```
     <ul>
       <li><div>long text 1</div></li>
       <li><div>long text 2</div></li>
       <li><div>long text 3</div></li>
       <li><div>long text 4</div></li>
    </ul>
```

with:

```
ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How can I prevent wrapping `<li>` to a new line?

I need truncate long text in last visible `<li>`, but not wrap the whole `<li>` with long text on new line

Comment: Would you want the user to be able to scroll to see the elements that aren't visible?

Comment: You can using medi screen

Comment: Using media queries by setting the desired breakpoints for Mobile, HD and 4K. So done set your `<li>` elements you want to hide to `display: none` in those media queries. Use `:nth-child(n)` for this or give the `<li>` elements a class name (or an ID).

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, I need truncate long text in last visible <li>, but not wrap the whole <li> with long text on new line

Comment: . There is **no** relaation between (the width of) the browser view and the screen resolution. For example, the browserr may be 900 px width on a 4K screen. Therefor you have to use the `@media()` to set the behavior of the `<ul>` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 25px;
}

ul > li,
ul > li > div {
  display: inline;
}

ul > li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>long text 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>long text 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>long text 3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>very very loooooong text content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of elements is always static, it can be accomplished using only CSS, but if it's dynamic, you'll have to introduce some JavaScript.

**HTML:**

```html
<ul id="my-list-id" class="my-list">
  <li>Child one</li>
  <li>Child two</li>
  <li>Child three</li>
  <li>Child four</li>
  <li>Child five</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS (`flexbox` + `media queries`):**

```css
.my-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.my-list > li {
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /* Assures there's no wrapping at any given point regardless of screen size. */
  margin-left: 4px;
}

/* Phone */
@media only screen and (max-width: 386px) {
  /* Assuming you always only need the first child to be visible
    For an unknown STATIC number of children, use 'li:not(:nth-child(NUM_OF_CHILDREN_VARIABLE))'
    For an unknown DYNAMIC number of children, set the 'NUM_OF_CHILDREN_VARIABLE' via JavaScript. */
  .my-list > li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
}
/* SD - Included for testing and as intermediary between phone resolution and full HD resolution,
  which you should probably have. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 387px) and (max-width: 1079px) {
  /* Assuming you always only need all but the last to be visible. */
  .my-list > li:last-child {
    display: none;
  }

  /* For an unknown STATIC number of children, use 'li:nth-last-child(-n+NUM)' where 'NUM'
    represents the last few items you do NOT wish to be visible.
    For an unknown DYNAMIC number, set the 'NUM' via JavaScript. */
  /*.my-list > li:nth-last-child(-n+NUM) {
    display: none;
  }*/
}
/* HD */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px) and (max-width: 2159px) {
  /* Assuming you always only need all but the last to be visible. */
  .my-list > li:last-child {
    display: none;
  }

  /* For an unknown STATIC number of children, use 'li:nth-last-child(-n+NUM)' where 'NUM'
    represents the last few items you do NOT wish to be visible.
    For an unknown DYNAMIC number, set the 'NUM' via JavaScript. */
  /*.my-list > li:nth-last-child(-n+NUM) {
    display: none;
  }*/
}
/* 4k - Assures all list items are visible. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 2160px) {
  .my-list > li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

**General JavaScript for dynamic number of list items:**

```js
let children = 5;

let myList = document.getElementById("my-list-id");
let listChildren = myList.children;

for (var i = 0; i < children; i++) {
  // First five children of type 'list item'
  if (listChildren[i].tagName == "li") {
    listChildren[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But can I prevent to wrapping <li> to a new line in CSS without JS ?

Comment: @Kirill Simply use `.my-list > li { flex-wrap: nowrap; }` in the CSS section. But keep in mind, the CSS will make it so it will never wrap regardless of screen size. If you want it not to wrap for a specific size, then simply put that code in the desired `@media` query.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul > li {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 1em;
}
.clip {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 144px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>long text 1</li>
   <li>long text 2</li>
   <li>long text 3</li>
   <li class=clip>long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, remove "max-width: 144px" and try to resize the browser.
<li> will wrap on new line